# How to use concat to get the path in .dir-locals.el with flycheck-clang-include-path

Tags: flycheck, directory-local-variables

I am using the following content to include headers to my project using `.dir-locals.el`

```
((c++-mode .
   ((flycheck-clang-language-standard . "c++14")
    (flycheck-clang-include-path
     "/Users/user/Documents/project_name/source"
     "/Users/user/Documents/project_name/source/library/include")
    )))
```

But, I do not want to explicit tell the path when it is located on my computer.

I was trying to use `(concat (file-name-directory (or load-file-name buffer-file-name)) "library/include")` for *.../source/library/include* and just `(file-name-directory (or load-file-name buffer-file-name)` for *.../source*. Since .dir-locals.el is located in */Users/user/Documents/project_name/source*

However when I replace the part with its respective instructions I got

```
Error while checking syntax automatically: (error "Value (\"/Users/user/Documents/project_name/source" (eval concat (file-name-directory (or load-file-name buffer-file-name)) \"library/include\") of flycheck-clang-include-path for option \"-I\" is not a list of strings")
```

I tried to use it with eval but did not work, How can I accomplish my goal?

EDIT: I test using `eval` as db48x suggested as the following:

```
((c++-mode .
    ((flycheck-clang-language-standard . "c++14")
    (eval .
        (setq flycheck-clang-include-path
            '("/Users/user/Documents/project_name/source"
         "/Users/user/Documents/project_name/source/library/include"))
        )
    )
))
```

That worked fine, but when adding replacing the second path with `(concat (file-name-directory (or load-file-name buffer-file-name)) "library/include")` got that it is not a list of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, `eval` isn't a function, it's just a symbol that tells it to evaluate a form rather than to set a variable. You need to do this instead:

```
((c++-mode .
   ((flycheck-clang-language-standard . "c++14")
    (eval .
     (setq flycheck-clang-include-path
           "/Users/user/Documents/project_name/source"
           (concat (file-name-directory (or load-file-name
                                            buffer-file-name))
                   "library/include")))))
```

Edit: Oops, you're right. In addition to leaving out a parenthesis, I left out something else that is important: I forgot to build a list of filenames. You almost fixed it correctly by putting the filenames in a quoted list, but the elements of a quoted list are not evaluated, so the quoted list just has the same non-filename stuff in it and gives you the same error. You can call the `list` function instead to build a list out of things that need to be evaluated. For example:

```
((c++-mode .
   ((flycheck-clang-language-standard . "c++14")
    (eval .
     (setq flycheck-clang-include-path
           (list "/Users/user/Documents/project_name/source"
                 (concat (file-name-directory (or load-file-name
                                                  buffer-file-name))
                         "library/include")))))))
```

I've actually tested it this time, so I know it works.

Comment: I got the same error saying the string paths are not a list of strings. `Error while checking syntax automatically: (error "Value \"/Users/user/Documents/project_name/source" (quote (concat (file-name-directory (or load-file-name buffer-file-name)) "library/include"))) of flycheck-clang-include-path for option \"-I\" is not a list of strings")`

Comment: You'll have to share the content of the file. I suspect you forgot to use eval. Also, the quote around the call to `concat` will prevent it from working.

Comment: Please check my update. I don't think the content of the file is the problem, what do you mean with the quote around concat, I had to add a ` to the list of paths to make it worked with raw strings. Without that quote as your suggestion, gives me the same error.

Comment: Yeah I was close, thank you for your help